# what kind of Anonymous Classes syntax is this in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Myinterface extends interface1 {
    name: string;
}

let mylet = <Myinterface >{};

mylet.name = "nana";
```

what is < Myinterface>{} ??
Is this one of the ways to create an object without a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [*type assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), another way of writing:

```
let mylet = {} as Myinterface;
```

It says "The object (`{}`) I'm assigning to `mylet` is of type `Myinterface`" (even though, in that code, it isn't — yet, not until you add the `name` property).

The `<Myinterface>{}` version is less common these days because of JSX, which wants to use `<Myinterface>` to start an element.

Given the question, I'm guessing you didn't write that code. For what it's worth, that code would be better written as:

```
let mylet = {
    name: "nana",
};
```

That has the same result as:

```
let mylet = {} as Myinterface;
mylet.name = "nana";
```

...since TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on shapes), not *nominal* (based on names).

But if you wanted to see `Myinterface` (the name) as the type of `mylet` when you hover it with the mouse, you could type it explicitly (I typically do, so that if I come back later and change the contents of the object, any changes that aren't compatible with `Myinterface` get flagged up):

```
let mylet: Myinterface = {
    name: "nana",
};
```

Comment: Well noted!!! I learned a lot thanks to you.

Comment: Even better: `let mylet: Myinterface = { /* … */ };`. Also, if `strictNullChecks` is enabled I don't think you could initialize `myLet` with an empty object.

Comment: @doup - Adding `: Myinterface` to the declaration will only change what you see when you hover `mylet`, but yeah, could be useful -- particularly if you come back later and change the object contents in some incompatible way. Re the empty object -- even with `strictNullChecks`, it lets you do `let mylet = {} as Myinterface;` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE9SVolBvAKGWORDgFsIAuZAZzClAHMBuAgXwIIBsIxly6XvwC8yPO2RxaaTOGjwkbAoOEA6MpWRiARGTI6WQA).

Comment: Oh, I see… I wasn't aware `as` behaved like that. Looks like a footgun to me. I definitely prefer `: MyInterface` as it won't let you init with an empty object.

Comment: @doup - Yeah, type assertions are fairly permissive. I try to avoid them wherever possible. And I'm actually with you, I always would include the type there. I didn't in the answer just to emphasize structural typing, but I'm not sure that was a useful thing to emphasize. :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is a type assertion. What you have there is the creation of an empty object `{}` and then asserting that the empty object respects the interface `Myinterface`.

Typescript will only perform minimal checks on assertions, so you can assert that `{}` respects the `Myinterface` even though it does not in this case (`name` is required). This is usually only a good idea if you then add the missing properties

Another form of type assertion would be `{} as MyInterface`